# how to `focus` to `tabpage` when close another `form`

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have two forms, `form0` and `form1`.
`form0` has a tabcontrol with three pages. (`tagpage1`, `tabpage2` and `tabpage3`)

I want `tabpage2` to be focused when `form1` closes. So basically, how do I control the state of a tabpage of another form's tabcontrol?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a static event in name space level not in form 
on closing Form1 fire this event and handle on form2 to select the require tab

Comment: Avoid static events like the plague.  They are, not explicitly unsubscribing the event causes a memory leak.  Since the event will keep a reference to the form object forever.  It can't be fixed by the garbage collector, you made the event static.

Answer (score 1):

That's what event handlers are designed to do.  You'll want to write a handler for the form's FormClosed event.  Similar to this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var frm = new form1();
        frm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frm_FormClosed);
        frm.Show();
    }

    void frm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
    }
```

Or more compactly:

```
        var frm = new form1();
        frm.FormClosed += delegate { tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2; };
        frm.Show();
```

With the Big Advantage that this is now entirely an implementation detail of form0, no special code or knowledge of form0 is required in the form1 class.

Comment: it's don't worked!
In `form1`, I don't call `tabControl` in `form0`

Comment: @DuyKhanh this code is for form0, not for form1. The code presented by Hans inside button1_click, should go where you open form1.

Comment: That's a rather key comment to the answer :)